# Lags at the junction of the connection between two videos in moviepy

Tags: python-3.x, video, ffmpeg, moviepy

After the video is merged, there is a slight duplication of the last second clip1 delay between the two merged videos. Tell me what could be the reason? The code:

```
clip1 = VideoFileClip("../1.mp4")
clip2 = VideoFileClip("../2.mp4")
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([clip1, clip2])
final_clip.write_videofile("../final.mp4")
```

An example of a lag is available at the link from the 2 second:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MPFmAeQan8LxnNkyKcv1YKuaAl4yTMY0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share `1.mp4` and `2.mp4` so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Rotem I solved the problem by cropping all the original videos. Thank you for your response!